# When using jsonwebtoken in express then what is the use of passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, jwt, json-web-token

Am beginner of node application, I Need to do authentication with [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), my colleges are saying to use passport with jwt,

I see jsonwebtoken itself doing, token issue/verify/decode, Then what is the use of Passport here..  Anybody please explain me the exact use of Passport JS

Comment: https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt

Comment: JWT's offer a state storage mechanism, Passport offers an authentication mechanism. Two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Passport** is an authentication middleware for Node.js. It helps you to introduce authentication to your application with use of a chosen *strategy* a.k.a. authentication mechanisms.

Such strategy would be for example a **JSON Web Token**.

More info here: https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt